# How can I translate "BETWEEN" function from Mysql to Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm developing some code, that needs to execute this query

(Traditional MYSQL)

```
SELECT * FROM `SistemaPuntuacions` WHERE `rankingActual` BETWEEN (SELECT `rankingActual` FROM `SistemaPuntuacions` WHERE `user_id` = $id) -5 AND (SELECT `rankingActual` FROM `SistemaPuntuacions` WHERE `user_id` = $id) +5 ORDER BY `rankingActual`"
```

Basically I've in SistemaPuntuacions a list of users, with their ranking (rankingActual). I need to show the 5 users above this users ranking and the 5 below.

But there's no "BETWEEN" in doctrine language, so I'm stuck there.

Can I get some help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually there [is](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) a BETWEEN in DQL. This code snippet is from the official docs.

```php
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.name FROM CmsUser u WHERE u.id BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2');
$query->setParameter(1, 123);
$query->setParameter(2, 321);
$usernames = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Damn, I trusted an answer from StackOverflow, from a search of google that said that there wasnt any BETWEEN in DQL, and that it was from MYSQL. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use native SQL like the this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `SistemaPuntuacions` WHERE `rankingActual` BETWEEN (SELECT `rankingActual` FROM `SistemaPuntuacions` WHERE `user_id` = $id) -5 AND (SELECT `rankingActual` FROM `SistemaPuntuacions` WHERE `user_id` = $id) +5 ORDER BY `rankingActual`';
$rows = $this->container->get('database_connection')->query($sql);
```

Comment: but is this returning data as array of Objects, as Doctrine do?